# Is FCM still better than polling when updating every 10 min is ok?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I want to have some sort of notification system for a mobile app with cordova/nativescript and using FCM seems like a lot of trouble for a little thing. I mean this is a private app, I don't want to publish it, just use it for my own purposes and I don't really want to buy a domain name and register for example a let's encrypt cert and renew it each month. All I need is sending a HTTP GET with an if-modified-since header every 10 mins to a certain IP and trigger an alert when there is a new event even at night. Is this a viable solution or would android/ios kill the application after a while? Would it completely drain the battery overnight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is always going to be active, you can implement your own polling mechanism.

If the app also needs to receive and display notifications when the user is not actively using it, there is no way to keep your own polling code running. In those scenarios FCM (Android+iOS+Web) or APNS (iOS only) are your only options.

Comment: It has to run in the background 24/7. Isn't adding a service a solution?

Comment: iOS doesn't hav a mechanism to have code that communicates with the network on its own while the app is not actively being used, and Android has been clamping down on such services for many versions.

Comment: Btw. I doubt this is legal. I mean it is building monopoly in mobile push notification systems. Microsoft lost that battle with MSIE and this seems like something worse, because after a certain number of messages you have to pay to be able to use their system.Their pricing is not high though, but still they cannot have a concurrency... https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: If you check that link, you'll see that FCM is free to use, as is APNS.

Comment: Ohh you are right, I thought the whole page is about FCM features and I was superficial.